# node.js streaming finance data from Yahoo or Google

Tags: node.js, streaming, finance, express

**UPDATE:** I want to continuously receive data.  Currently, this returns one data set.  I think the only alternative is polling/setInterval techniques that achieve only the effect of streaming.

Is it possible to retrieve streaming finance data from Yahoo or Google using node.js?
I know that they have no public API available for the data I'm trying to retrieve.

I've written this using express but the data is not streaming.

```
    var express = require('express'),
        http = require('http'),
        app = express.createServer();

  // Using either Google or Yahoo...

    var client = http.createClient(80,'download.finance.yahoo.com');
    var request = client.request('GET', '/d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG&f=snr', { host: 'download.finance.yahoo.com' });

  //var client = http.createClient(80,'www.google.com');
    //var request = client.request('GET', '/finance/info?client=ig&q=CSCO', { host: 'www.google.com'});

    request.end();

    request.addListener('response', function (response) {
      response.setEncoding(encoding="utf8");
      response.addListener('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
      response.addListener('end',function(data) {
        console.log('End');
      });
    });

    app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: That should work. What's your actual problem?

Comment: Dave, answers are answers. Just edit your question if you have an update, correction or something.